# What is the difference between vscode remote-ssh and remote-tunnel connections

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-tunnel, vscode-remote, remote-tunnel

How does VSCODE's [Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) compare against [Remote Tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) for development in terms of speed and code protection?

At a glance, it appears that SSH shares the workload (extension) across both machines
[image: Remote SSH]

While the Remote Tunnel works entirely on the remote/server machine
[image: Tunnel]

Does Remote Tunnel connect both machines over the internet? How does it impact speed?

Is Remote SSH always preferable when it is possible?

Comment: in SSH remote the local VSC is just a smart terminal that shows a view of the remote VSC, maybe it edits the files in the local instance but it stored it on a remote file system/workspace.

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory answer? In particular, I was curious about performance: Is Remote SSH faster than Remote Tunnel? Or not?

Comment: I do not use Remote Tunnel yet as I am not an admin on the remote machine, meaning I have to ask someone to upgrade the VSCODE etc. on the remote machine. Also, I like that SSH distributes the load on both machines, which seems like an advantage for me. What can work locally doesn't have to go through the Internet. I am worried if SSH is being deprecated in favor of Tunnels.

Answer (score 2):

"code protection": this is followed by [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 6608](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6608), but without official documentation (yet).

[Issue 8110](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8110) gives an example of using tunnel instead of SSH:

> I'm using the code tunnel on a multi-node HPC cluster.
> This means that I can run it from any number of machines (depending on where my job is scheduled), but all share the same NFS-mounted home directory.
>
> However, I've noticed that the generated token is tied to a specific machine: if I run a new code tunnel from a different machine, it will give the prompt:
>
> ```
> To grant access to the server, please log into https://github.com/login/device 
> and use code XXXX-XXXX
> ```
>
> This appears to modify the `~/.vscode-cli/token.json` file.
> If I run code tunnel again from the same machine, I don't see the prompt, but I do if I change machines (including ones previously authenticated).

With confirmation from Microsoft:

> The token secret is encrypted(/obfuscated) using information specific to the machine. We do not currently support sharing this between multiple machines.
>
> The obfuscation is used to provide some modicum of security on systems with more permissive keychains, i.e. ones that don't segregate secrets between different consuming applications on a system level.
> See [`microsoft/vscode`@`cli/src/auth.rs`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/32cb3193ca9f20cb45d80abec94457783635312b/cli/src/auth.rs#L186)

This was fixed with [PR 175940](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/175940).

All this points to a different encryption mechanism than SSH.

Answer (score 0):

### Remote Tunnels VS Remote Development VS Code Server

###### as mentioned in [code.visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels)

> Visual Studio Code Remote Development allows you to use a container,
> remote machine, or the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as a
> full-featured development environment.

> Remote Development lets your local VS Code installation transparently
> interact with source code and runtime environments on other machines
> (whether virtual or physical) by moving the execution of certain
> commands to a "remote server", the VS Code Server. The VS Code Server
> is quickly installed by VS Code when you connect to a remote endpoint
> and can host extensions that interact directly with the remote
> workspace, machine, and file system.

We've released this VS Code Server backend component as a service you can run yourself (which you may read more about in its documentation), rather than it only being solely installed and managed by the Remote Development extensions.

---

Accessing the VS Code Server involves a few components:

The VS Code Server: Backend server that makes VS Code remote experiences possible.

- Remote Tunnels extension: Extension that facilitates the connection to the
- remote machine, where you have an instance of the server running.